# why we need base stage for containerizing asp.net app in Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

below is the default docker file

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app #<------------------------------------------
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ExampleApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ExampleApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ExampleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build  # <----the build folder is not being used?

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ExampleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app  # <------------------------------duplicated instruction?
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.dll"]
```

isn't that `WORKDIR /app` is a duplicated instruction? can we remove the `WORKDIR /app` in the final stage? same as the "build" folder in `/app/build`, the "build" folder is not being used, so why it is there?

I also dont' understand why we need the base stage in the begining, can we remove the first base stage and do:

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ExampleApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ExampleApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ExampleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ExampleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.dll"]
```

Comment: Yes, they're duplicates and you can safely remove one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base stage is there to support ["fast mode" debugging in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#debugging). The stage is not **needed**, but is useful if you are debugging in VS and would like the process to be faster. If you do remove the base state you should turn off fast mode debugging by adding this to your project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   <ContainerDevelopmentMode>Regular</ContainerDevelopmentMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```